# Debug MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any way to debug a MySQL WHERE clause? Maybe like a line by line code debugger? I'm trying to figure out why a somewhat complex WHERE clause is selecting a table row that I don't believe it should be. Being able to see which conditionals are returning true of false would greatly help.

Comment: That's very interesting.  While waiting for an answer, please post an MCVE because it might take someone less time to spot your problem than someone else to suggest an SQL debugger.

Comment: No, there is no debug system in mysql. but you can just try to comment or uncomment parts of your query in any mysql console you use (mysql workbench for example)

Comment: Another alternative is to copy the query, replacing the selected fields with the fields involved in the where conditions and the various where conditions and/or parts of conditions, so you can see the values for the expressions; and replacing the where with a condition to limit the result to the row it was returning you think it should not have. _And, as always, make sure to parenthesize your conditions to force evaluation order; being "smart" with precedence just makes conditions harder to read & makes the next person who has to read it wonder what the person who wrote it actually intended.)_

Answer (score 0):

Select `Designer` tab in you `phpmyadmin` and you will see how the tables are connected. This is one of the ways you can 'debug' your tables.

[image]